# Could not upload jar file to lambda function from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I am trying to upload the jar file(abc-test.jar) from s3 bucket to lambda function using below cli command but got an error saying could not unzip uploaded file.

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name testing-upload-jar-lambda --s3-bucket testing-jar --s3-key abc-test.jar --region us-east-1
```

An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the UpdateFunctionCode operation: Could not unzip uploaded file. Please check your file, then try to upload again.

Any idea why I am getting this error?